# Live streaming Flash video

Tags: live-streaming, flash-video

what software do I need, if I want to make a video live stream, than could be watched in a flash player?

Preferably Linux tools. I'd like to peercast it to a hub, and multicast it from there, much like webradio works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) and one of their recommended [stream partners](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/fvss/).  Here's a [guide to streaming](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/beginner_live_fms3.html) with [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/).

Alternatively we use a streaming appliance called the [Digital Rapids StreamZHD Media Encoder](http://www.digital-rapids.com/Products/IndividualProducts/StreamZHD.aspx).  It's a fantastic piece of hardware but it cost around $35,000 USD

Comment: OK, it's WAAAAAYY over my budged, isn't there any way of cheap flash streaming?

Comment: you either need a hosted solution, or host your own.  With the Flash Media Server, your cost up front is about $1000 for the software plus the cost of hardware.  Then you only pay for your bandwidth and infrastructure.  If you go with a hosted solution, you can probably land around $30 / month and up.  But then the host manages everything for you.